# Less stylesheet doesnt get rendered when I prefix address with www

Tags: less

I use lessCSS. And problem I have is that if in CodeIgniter I set base URL as http://www.mysite.com, and in my browser I go to mysite.com less doesnt render.

And the other way around...

Console gives me this:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxx Origin http://mysite.lt is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

less-1.2.1.min.js:8Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your .htaccess file (assuming you are using Apache):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That will always add www. even if the user doesn't type it. That should solve your issue.

To do this and remove index.php from urls I use this block of code for my EE installs (which uses CI)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php

        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

        # Redirects index.php when user adds them to a URL

        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/system/.*
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

        # Appends www when absent

        RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.com [NC,OR]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

First block is your standard EE based rewrite to remove index.php from all your URLS. The second block of code is a nice addition that keeps urls, where index.php is added anyway by the user, from resolving and giving you duplicate urls with search engines (thus hurting SEO). Instead it properly forwards to the correct URL if it exists, or returns a 404 where appropriate. And of course the final block of code adds (or can remove) www.

Comment: I actually did this already, but the other way around. As in always removing the www. Is there any pros or cons to either approach?? As in always removing vs always prepending the www?

Comment: Not really, as long as you are consistent. Some people prefer to remove it because it is shorter, others prefer www. because its more common. SEO wise it doesn't matter. Did that fix your problem?

Comment: Yeah it did! Thanks! Except a tiny thing... I have another bit of mod_rewrite.. The one to get rid of index.php in CI... When I got to site, that one doesnt get invoked, and index.php appears on the URL.. Not really a big deal at all, but would be nice to know how those 2 rules could live together?

Comment: Updated my answer with the code to allow both to work together.